# Url rewriting on custom post with CPT UI plugin

Tags: customization, url-rewriting

I checked all subjects in forum about this but i didn't found way to resolve my problem. sorry for my english, i'm french.. :)

So.. i got a custom post listing ( with template listing pro ) there : http://easycowork.fr/bureau/easy-office-lille/

I created a custom post named **service** and i display all service associate on listing on the listing single page. When i click on a service, i display his data on the same page with a `GET` parameter ( the service id ) like this : http://easycowork.fr/bureau/easy-office-lille/?show_service=196

But i need the name of service instead of `show_service=196` after the name of listing "easy-office-lille"

How can i do that ? I'm really lost in url rewriting

I use [Custom post type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin to create custom post, I added rewrite option to true, and Custom Rewrite Slug option to service and registered permalink but that didn't work.

Thanks for help !

Comment: how do you store which listing should be in the URL of each service?

Comment: i'm not sure to understand your answer ( im french ), but.. my service is displaying on listing single page. i have associate each service with listing ( i got a front form to add service, i got a select to choose listing i want for the service ) so easy on single listing page to know which service is from the listing. when you are on listing page, you click on service's image and the page reload with $_GET parameter and i hide some listing data to display service's data. Sorry if is not your question :/

Comment: Where is the association between listing and service stored? Is that post meta data? To generate a permalink for a service, you have to be able to get the name of the listing that it is associated to.

Comment: the association is in service's custom field so post meta data yes, i register the name of listing. So i know the name of the listing because i'm on the listing page, and if i have to create new page for my service, i can know which listing is associate to, but i really don't how to do this

Answer (score 0):

To achieve result for custom URL rewriting for your custom post type `service` using the Custom Post Type UI plugin,

you can follow these steps

**Register the custom post type with the desired rewrite slug**

Register Custom Post Type with Rewrite Slug:

> In the Custom Post Type UI plugin, go to `CPT UI` > `Add/Edit Post Types` and edit your `"service"` post type. Make sure you have set the
> `Rewrite` option to true and the `Custom Rewrite Slug` option to the
> desired slug, `e.g( service )`

**Add a rewrite rule to handle the custom URL structure**

> Add a custom rewrite rule to handle the custom URL structure. You can
> do this by adding code to your themes `functions.php` file or a
> `custom plugin`

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^bureau/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&show_service=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
```

This rule will rewrite URLs like `http://easycowork.fr/bureau/easy-office-lille/123` to `http://easycowork.fr/index.php?pagename=bureau/easy-office-lille&show_service=123`

**Modify your template to handle the custom URL structure**

> In your template file `single-service.php`, you can retrieve the
> service ID from the show_service parameter and display the
> corresponding content.

```
$service_id = isset($_GET['show_service']) ? intval($_GET['show_service']) : 0;
if ($service_id) {
    // Query the service post based on the ID and display its content
    // Example: $service_post = get_post($service_id);
} else {
    // Display default content for the listing page
}
```

Remember to flush the rewrite rules after adding or modifying them. You can do this by visiting the `"Settings" > "Permalinks"` page in your WordPress admin and clicking the `Save Changes` button

After following these steps, you should be able to access your service pages with URLs like `http://easycowork.fr/bureau/easy-office-lille/123`, where `123` is the ID of the service